# Auto logging in catch block, only when exception variable is annotated, for Java or Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, annotations, code-generation, aop

I want to do this for Java or Kotlin: 
given the code below

> try { ...
>   }
>   catch (**@AutoLog** e: Exception) {
>   //position1
>   }

add a logging statement at position1 automatically during build time. I can add code with AspectJ for catch block(for both Java and Kotlin), but it's for all catch blocks, I can't check whether @AutoLog annotation is present and add code only when it is. So I think I have to turn to APT(Annotation processing tool) for Java (or KAPT for Kotlin)?

Btw, I found a KAPT code generation example here: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-examples/tree/master/gradle/kotlin-code-generation
 , but it generates code to separate file, while what I want to do is modify the original file/class and add a statement in catch block.

Comment: The apt is not made for modifying existing code. You can try http://notatube.blogspot.com/2010/11/project-lombok-trick-explained.html but I don't think it works in Kotlin.
The best I can think of is generating a new class which uses the annotation and logs the annotated variable.

Comment: @Bal0r Thanks for the excellent link, I found it very helpful. Will look into annotation processor + AST(abstract syntax tree) manipulation approach. The @ cleanup in Lombok uses annotations on local variable and modifies existing code. So that's a feasibility proof. What I want to do must also be feasible with same approach.

Comment: I think @Bal0r's comment is the correct answer here. You need to do what Lombok does with the AST modification by APT. Bal0r: you should change it from a comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using annotations, you can use some of Kotlin's features to create your own functions that operate similarly to the standard `try { ... } catch { ... }`, but also log exceptions. Here's a quick example:

```
sealed class Result<S>

class Success<S>(val value: S) : Result<S>()
class Error<S, E : Throwable>(val error: E) : Result<S>()

fun <S> loggingTry(block: () -> S): Result<S> {
    return try {
        Success(block())
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        Error(e)
    }
}

inline infix fun <reified E : Throwable, R> Result<out R>.catch(handler: (E) -> R): R {
    return when (this) {
        is Success -> value
        is Error<*, *> -> if (error is E) {
            println("Error $error is being handled") // replace this with your own logging
            handler(error)
        } else throw error
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val x = loggingTry {
        1 / 0
    } catch { e: ArithmeticException ->
        3
    }

    println("Result: $x")

    loggingTry {
        1 / 0
    } catch { e: NullPointerException ->
        println("This won't be called, the exception will just be re-thrown")
    }
}
```

This code generates the following output:

```
Error java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero is being handled
Division result was 3
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at MainKt$main$1.invoke(Main.kt:34)
    at MainKt$main$1.invoke(Main.kt)
    at MainKt.loggingTry(Main.kt:8)
    at MainKt.main(Main.kt:33)
```

This isn't a perfect solution, since it's more limited (e.g. no multi-catch) and has a slightly different syntax, but the end result is comparable.